# Nested prefix and new interactive API

Tags: django-rest-framework

ViewSet with a nested prefix seems not to work with the new interactive API documentation

e.g.
    router.register(r'contact/messages', MessageViewSet, base_name='contact-messages')

Is there another way to achieve the same result?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Django `urlpatterns` like,

```
urlpatterns += [url(r'^contact/messages', MessageViewSet.as_view(), name='contact-messages')]
```

Comment: It doesn't work. "Contact" doesn't appear on the left menu of the documentation.